# Plotting curve through histograms in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, modeling

I have been trying to plot a von Bertalanffy growth curve (describing growth of fish over time) derived from modal progression analysis of simulated length frequency data on faceted/multipanel histograms. Here's how the data and the plot looks:

Monthly size frequency progression

[image]

```
> head(L_data)
  Length Month
1   18.5    01
2   61.5    01
3   61.5    01
4   62.5    01
5   62.5    01
6   63.5    01sc
```

Here's the code to generate the graph without the curves

```
  geom_histogram(bins = 60, color = "black", fill = "white") +
  facet_wrap(~Month, ncol = 1) +
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                     axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                     strip.text.x = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid = element_blank(),
                     panel.border = element_blank()) +
  ylab("") + xlim(5,100)
```

Here's how I want the figure to look like

[image]

The ideal would be to be able to draw a non linear curve over the histograms. The parameters are estimated through Bayesian inference. I would also be willing to plot that using R base functions.

Comment: This... will be tricky. I'd suggest sharing (just) enough data to plot histograms for  3 months (or `set.seed()`ed code to generate fake data) as well as specifics about the overlaying curves for that sample data. It will make it much easier for people to help you if their first step is copy/paste sample data rather than generate sample data.